# EmberJs + Sinon Stub not called with proper object

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ember.js, qunit, sinon

I am having following code which tests whether proper action method is being invoked or not, however with the setup i am having it seems that different controller instances are getting generated and hence test is failing. Any pointers will be helpful,

```
module('SearchViewtests', {
setup : function() {

    App.reset();

    Ember.run(this, function(){

        this.controller = App.SearchController.create({
        });

        sinon.stub(this.controller._actions, "search");

        this.view = App.SearchView.create({
            controller : this.controller,
            container : App.__container__,
            context : this.controller
        });

        this.view.append();
    });
},
teardown : function(){
    Ember.run(this, function () {
        this.view.remove(); 
    });
    this.controller._actions.search.restore();
}});

test("on search button click invokes search action on controller", function(){

var button = this.view.$(".searchButton:button");

button.trigger('click');

ok(this.controller._actions.search.calledOnce, "Search page called");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one context for `this`, rather than a setup `this` and a test `this`:

```
test("on search button click invokes search action on controller",
  function(){

   var button = this.view.$(".searchButton:button");

   button.trigger('click');

   this.controller = App.SearchController.create({
    });

    sinon.stub(this.controller._actions, "search");

    this.view = App.SearchView.create({
        controller : this.controller,
        container : App.__container__,
        context : this.controller
    });

    this.view.append();
   ok(this.controller._actions.search.calledOnce, "Search page called");
});
```